# IntelliJ CE 12 won't start on Mac after upgrading Java to 1.7_25

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I recently upgraded the Java from 1.6 to 1.7_25 on my Mac OS 10.6.8 by following this blog http://timhooker.blogspot.com/2013/05/install-java-jdk7-on-mac-osx-snow.html.

When I try to click on the IntelliJ icon on my dock, it hangs and wont' launch. I tried to take a look at the /Library/Preferences/IdeaIC12/options/ide.general.xml and make sure it does not load the last project (just in case that project crashed). Still not working.

Also tried to open from Terminal: open -a /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 12\ CE.app/, but it's not working. This makes me wonder if IntelliJ 12 CE works on Java 1.7 on Mac ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cant try 1.7_45?

Answer (score 3):

Change `JVMVersion` to `1.7*` in `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 13\ CE.app/Contents/Info.plist`.